# Add new column with its data to existing DataFrame using

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In scala I have a List[String] which I want to add as a new Column to an existing DataFrame.

**Original DF:**

```
Name  | Date
======|===========
Rohan | 2007-12-21
...   | ...
...   | ...
```

Suppose want to add a new Column of Department

**Expected DF:**

```
Name | Date       | Department
=====|============|============
Rohan| 2007-12-21 | Comp
...  | ...        | ...
...  | ...        | ...
```

How can I do this in Scala?

Comment: Is there any relation between the columns ? Any rules ?

Comment: So you want to join them on? I wouldn't think you just want to add some random values.

Comment: Probaly you want to join your df on name with another df.

Comment: @eliasah No rules just a new column of data.

Comment: @Reactormonk Just need to add a new data column not sure if I need to use joins

Comment: You want to add a column based on what ? what's it's content ?

Comment: @eliasah a completely new column as you can see in the example above like adding a department for each person in this list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one way like just create the dataframe of name and listvalues and join both the dataframe with name column

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue

```
val newrows = dataset.rdd.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
      .join(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(results).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap))
      .values
      .map { case (row: Row, x: String) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ x) }
```

Still need some exact explanation of it.